# How do cursed tools identify their owners?

Tags: cube-x-cursed-x-curious

I see that cursed tools pass from a owner to the next when the owner relinquish ownership (like when Haruaki asked Kirika to give him the Tragic Black River belt) or when the owner dies and someone claims ownership (the The Indigo Vessel and Rawhide FCD comes to mind).

Since the curses normally affects their owners or people related to their owners, how exactly are the ownership given? Can tools decide to change ownership without killing their owners or with their owners relinquishing ownership?